# How to write true type font information in AFP file?

Tags: afp

If we use raster or outline fonts in AFP printing then it writes all the font information in AFP output file. We can see it through AFP file viewer. But if we use true type font in AFP then we  don't get the font information correctly. 
We have used EBCDIC for raster and outline fonts.
And TrueType / OpenType fonts are encoded as UTF16BE.

Can you please help us in this, How to write true type font information in AFP file format?

Comment: You may need to share some hex dump of your documents so the actual problem could be reproduced. Also, what's your environment? If it is a viewer, the program name, version, and relevant config information (fonts section) would be useful.

Comment: Outline font information in output AFP file:
FONT0001  Type=Font Character Set Object
CZTNN00
FaceName=Times New Roman  WeightClass=5  WidthClass=5  PtSize=0  Flags=()
MaxW=0  MaxH=0  DPI=0x0  ByteAlign=1  PatternsSize=29146  FontTechnology=Type1 PFB (Outline)
CharRotation=0  SpaceCharInc=250  FNInumber=0  UniformCharInc=0  NominalCharInc=0  UniformBLoffset=0  UniformAspace=0 EMspaceInc=889 FigureSpaceInc=500
MaxAscender=877  MaxDescender=216  ULposition=65403  ULwidth=49

Comment: True type font information in output AFP file:
FONT0001  Type=Object Container
FONT0001  Comment=  TimeStamp=   ByteCount=0
<Object Data>
<Object Data>

Comment: Code snippet used to write true type font information:
BYTE aData_2[] = {
    // TRIPLET - Data-Object Font Descriptor Triplet X'8B'.
    0x10,                                 // Length
    0x8B,                                 // Triplet tag ID = 0x8B
    0x00,                                 // Flags, 0x00 = No MICR printing.
    0x20,                                 // Font technology, 0x20 = TrueType/OpenType

Comment: HIBYTE(xSize), LOBYTE(xSize),         // Vertical font size (1440ths of an inch)
    0x00, 0x00,                           // Horizontal scale factor (not specified = 0x0000)
    0x00, 0x00,                           // Character rotation (0x0000 = no rotation, 0x2D00 = 90, 0x5A00 = 180, 0x8700 = 270)
    0x00, 0x03,                           // Encoding environment (0x0003 = Windows)
    0x00, 0x01,                           // Encoding environment identifier (0x0001 = Unicode)
    0x00, 0x00                            // Reserved, must be 0x0000
}

Comment: Just one more step please. Edit your question and put the hex dump there. Start each line with two or more spaces so that it was formatted in a readable way.